# Percorrer um dict até ficar vazio no Python

Tags: python, lista, dicionário

Gostaria como fazer para percorrer enquanto uma lista composta de valores e chaves for diferente de zero, adiciona apenas os valores (values()) em uma lista? O código que tenho é esse:

```
hey = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']
print("hey", hey)
lol = [32, 54, 56, 64]
print("lol", lol)
lil = dict(zip(lol, hey))
print("lil: ",lil)
pop = list(zip(lil.values(), lil.keys()))
print("pop sem ordenar: ", pop)

sorted(pop, reverse=True)
print("pop ordenado: ", pop)

#for i in lil:
     #  print("i: ",i)
     #  print("lil[i]: ", lil[i])

max_value = max(pop)

print("max_value: ", max_value)
novo_lil = lil[max_value[1]]
del lil[max_value[1]]
print("lil nova: ",lil)
```

Tentei fazer isso, mas não funcionou:

```
hey = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']
print("hey", hey)
lol = [32, 54, 56, 64]
print("lol", lol)
lil = dict(zip(lol, hey))
print("lil: ",lil)
pop = list(zip(lil.values(), lil.keys()))
print("pop sem ordenar: ", pop)

sorted(pop, reverse=True)
print("pop ordenado: ", pop)

#for i in lil:
     #  print("i: ",i)
     #  print("lil[i]: ", lil[i])

max_value = max(pop)

while not(lil[max_value[1]]):
    print("max_value: ", max_value)
    novo_lil = lil[max_value[1]]
    del lil[max_value[1]]
    print("lil nova: ",lil)
```

Alguém pode auxiliar-me? O que estou fazendo na verdade é ordenar um dict e depois eu adiciono somente os valores dele em uma lista, apenas isso.

Comment: Eu não entendi sua dúvida, mas percebi que está usando a função sorted de forma errada, você deve fazer assim "pop = sorted(pop,reverse=True)". Se puder explicar melhor a dúvida.

Comment: Certo @PauloHenriqueCardoso, é assim: tenho duas listas. Cada valor de hey corresponde a um valor de lol. Logo 'item1' tem valor 32, 'item2' tem valor 54 e assim por diante! Preciso ordenar a lista hey com base na lista lol em forma decrescente, de forma que lol fique: [64, 56, 54, 32] mas a lista hey também deve ser ordenada correspondente com cada valor de lol: hey = ['item4', 'item3', 'item2', 'item1']

Comment: A forma que encontrei com meu amigo @Miguel foi de relacioná-los por meio de um dict como é feito em: lil = dict(zip(lol, hey))

Comment: Então eu transformo esse meu dict em uma lista e ordeno ela, como você ali corrigiu. Já que não é possível ordenar um dict, pensei em pegar o maior valor do dict e adicionar por ordem em uma lista, mas apenas seus values()

Comment: Para que no final eu tenha hey = ['item4', 'item3', 'item2', 'item1'] ordenado com base na lista lol, consegui explicar?

Comment: É que é um pouco difícil de explicar mesmo, peço desculpas por isso.

Comment: Ainda não sei se entendi, mas o seu problema parece ser o fato de o dicionario não ser ordenado, para isso você pode usar o [Ordered dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) da biblioteca Collections. Mas veja se essas duas linhas de codigo apos ordenar a lista "pop" resolvem seu problema :for i in range(len(hey)):
     hey[i] = pop[i][0]

Comment: pot favor, munde o rsumário - ("enunciado") da questão. Atualmente não tem nada em comum com o problema exposto.

Answer (score 3):

Nossa - - muita complciação para coisa que fica bem simples em Python.

Dicionários tem os métodos `keys`, `values`e `items` que permitem acesso aos seus membros, e a poderosa construção de list-comprehension, que deixa você aplicar qualquer expressão em cada item de uma sequência para gerar uma lista.

ENtão é só fazer:

```
hey = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']
lol = [32, 54, 56, 64]

dct = dict(zip(lol, hey))
result = [valor for chave, valor in sorted(dct.items(), reverse=True)]
```

Onde `dct` é um dicionári que relaciona as duas listas, como você já fez - aí percorremos todos os itens desse dicionário já ordenados pela chave na chamada ao "sorted" - como você quer em ordem decrescente, usamos o "reverse". E, de cada item, pegamos o segundo valor - que é o valor associado na primeira lista original.

Answer (score 0):

Para ordenar uma lista de acordo com a outra eu desenvolvi a seguinte solução:

```
hey = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']
lol = [32, 54, 56, 64]

''' vamos cria uma lista de transposição com a posição original
e a nova posição do item. '''
transposicao = []
for posicao_nova, i in enumerate(sorted(lol, reverse=True)):
    posicao_original = lol.index(i)
    transposicao.append([posicao_nova, posicao_original])

# após guardar as posições, efetivamente alteramos a lista lol
lol = sorted(lol, reverse=True)

# agora utilizamos a lista de transposição para reordenar a lista hey
nova_hey = []
for i in transposicao:
    nova_hey.append(hey[i[1]])

hey = nova_hey

print(hey, lol)
```

O resultado será o desejado: ['item4', 'item3', 'item2', 'item1'] [64, 56, 54, 32]

Uma versão mais simples e mais "pythonica":

```
from operator import itemgetter

hey = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']
lol = [32, 54, 56, 64]

# junta as listas e ordena de acordo com os valors da segunda lista     (lol no caso)
ordena_junto = sorted(list(zip(hey, lol)), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

# extrai as listas ordernadas
hey, lol = zip(*ordena_junto)
print(hey, lol)
```

Resultado: ('item4', 'item3', 'item2', 'item1') (64, 56, 54, 32)

Espero que tenha ajudado a resolver o seu problema.